# Error in httr::content(req, as = "parsed") : is.response(x) is not TRUE

Tags: get

I'm trying to download data through the function getLocTOS() to access NEON web data.
The console answer is:

*No internet connection detected. Cannot access NEON API.
Error in httr::content(req, as = "parsed") : is.response(x) is not TRUE*

What can I do?

I don't know what to do.